# ASP.NET MVC: ActionDescriptor.UniqueId how unique?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, uniqueidentifier

I don't unterstand ActionDescriptor.UniqueId. Is this unique like a type in an application (but cnstant over time), or does every request gets a new unique id?

Can I use it to differentiate between several calls ot the same controller method, like by different users?

Lots of Greetings!

Volker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had no experience with the `UniqueId` property, so I did a bit of research using the MVC source (which is where you should always start for a question like this).

**ActionDescriptor**

```
private string CreateUniqueId()
{
    return DescriptorUtil.CreateUniqueId(GetType(), ControllerDescriptor, ActionName);
}
```

`ActionDescriptor's` unique ID contains its `ControllerDescriptor's` unique ID as well.

**ControllerDescriptor**

```
private string CreateUniqueId()
{
    return DescriptorUtil.CreateUniqueId(GetType(), ControllerName, ControllerType);
}
```

**DescriptorUtil (internal class)**

```
public static string CreateUniqueId(IEnumerable<object> parts)
{
    // returns a unique string made up of the pieces passed in
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (object part in parts)
    {
        // We can special-case certain part types

        MemberInfo memberInfo = part as MemberInfo;
        if (memberInfo != null)
        {
            AppendPartToUniqueIdBuilder(builder, memberInfo.Module.ModuleVersionId);
            AppendPartToUniqueIdBuilder(builder, memberInfo.MetadataToken);
            continue;
        }

        IUniquelyIdentifiable uniquelyIdentifiable = part as IUniquelyIdentifiable;
        if (uniquelyIdentifiable != null)
        {
            AppendPartToUniqueIdBuilder(builder, uniquelyIdentifiable.UniqueId);
            continue;
        }

        AppendPartToUniqueIdBuilder(builder, part);
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

You can see that the value is created from type information and controller/action information. It should be unique among all other actions in the application. It does not appear that the parameters (if any) accepted by the action impact the ID.

> Can I use it to differentiate between several calls ot the same
>   controller method, like by different users?

No user information is contained in the ID generated.

`OutputCacheAttribute` is a consumer of `UniqueId`. This strongly indicates that the value--while unique across actions--is predictable between calls. Otherwise, it would be useless for caching purposes.

Comment: Thanks a whole lot! So, for call tracking I'll insert a filter that adds a Guid.NewGuid() into the HttpContext.